# How can I create custom view using Zxing?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm trying to create a custom view for scanning QR codes using Zxing

Actually I can implement this library on my gradle's dependencies and everything goes perfectly with the default layout view (`'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'`)

Now I want to create my own view but this classes are read-only files

How can I import zxing and edit the core code?

I also checked this project and I realized that in this project I am able to edit the full code : https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

Answer (score 3):

Use this class:

```
package com.company.project.view.activities

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.zxing.Result
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_scaling_scanner.*
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView
import com.company.project.R

class ScanActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private val FLASH_STATE = "FLASH_STATE"
    private val AUTOFOCUS_STATE = "AUTOFOCUS_STATE"

    private var mScannerView: ZXingScannerView? = null
    private var mFlash: Boolean = false
    private var mAutofocus: Boolean = true
    private var resultText: String = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner)

        mScannerView = ZXingScannerView(this)

        content_frame.addView(mScannerView)

        mScannerView?.setFlash(mFlash)
        mScannerView?.setAutoFocus(true)

        switchFlash.setOnClickListener({
            mFlash = !mFlash
            mScannerView?.setFlash(mFlash)
        })

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mScannerView?.setResultHandler(this)
        mScannerView?.setAspectTolerance(0.2f)
        mScannerView?.setFlash(mFlash)
        mScannerView?.setAutoFocus(mAutofocus)
        mScannerView?.startCamera()

        switchFlash.setChecked(mFlash)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mScannerView?.stopCamera()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState?.putBoolean(FLASH_STATE, mFlash)
        outState?.putBoolean(AUTOFOCUS_STATE, mAutofocus)
    }

    override fun handleResult(result: Result?) {
        mScannerView?.resumeCameraPreview(this)

        if (result == null) {
            return
        }

        mScannerView?.stopCamera()

        resultText = result.text;
        val resultIntent: Intent= Intent().putExtra("BRCode", resultText)
        setResult(1, resultIntent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

this layoutView:

activity_scanner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#222"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switchFlash"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/flashValue"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
                    android:paddingLeft="300dp" android:layout_gravity="center"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and call like this from your MainActivity

```
    scanView.setOnClickListener {
        scanQRCode()
    }

fun scanQRCode(){
    val intent = Intent(this, ScanActivity::class.java)
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (data == null) {
        showIncorrectQRCodeDialogue()
        return
    }

    if (data.getStringExtra("BRCode")!=null) {

        val brCode: String = data.getStringExtra("BRCode")


           val intent = Intent(this, NewActivity::class.java);

           startActivity(intent);

    }else {
        showIncorrectQRCodeDialogue()
    }
}
```

You will be able to edit the scan layout and scan activity class to your custom requirements.

I hope this assists you. Happy coding.